# How to parse function name with arguments in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, tokenize

I am building a module for my own PHP framework, so my question is very specific and special. It's difficult to explain my question so I will go ahead and show it on code below.

I have a little piece of PHP in a $code variable, it looks like this:

```
$code = "___echo(TODAY_IS, date('j.n.Y', time()), time());";
```

What I need is to parse this $code variable and I want to get this result:

```
 $result = array(
   'function_name' => "___echo",
   'arguments' => array(
     0 => "TODAY_IS",
     1 => "date('j.n.Y', time())",
     2 => "time()"
   )
 );
```

I am thinking and I have tried using some regex, but neither worked sufficiently well. I also tried using Tokenizer, however I wasn't successful either.

Thanks for any hints or help in advance.

Comment: It will be exceedingly difficult to do this right all the time. Any framework, that resorts to writing its own interpreter, is a failed framework in my eyes. You should simplify the syntax of your `$code` string.

Comment: LOL, I can't say I wasn't expecting this comment :-) 
On my defense, the framework is doing some really advanced things and downside is I have to deal with such strange problems like this one.

Comment: Give an example of such an advanced thing and I will show a way without the need of a parser.

Comment: >>> the framework is doing some really advanced things

This is not **advanced**. This is only **BADvanced**.

Comment: Just to give explanation where this piece of code comes from - it's module which precompiles PHP templates with i18n support so heavy stuff is dealt with only once and next requests are served with compiled templates.

Comment: You don't mean 'compile', do you? It's 'pre-processing' at most. The resulting code is still PHP, so there's no change in language level, nothing is compiled. There are much easier ways to do internationalization and localization support, and they are not 'heavy stuff'. Nevertheless the example helps to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, you are right with the 'compile'. By 'heavy stuff' I was talking about all other things the frameworkis doing. I18n is just a small part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a shot using [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser). It's likely going to be more useful than tokenizer or some freaky regex.

#### Example:

```
$code = "___echo(TODAY_IS, date('j.n.Y', time()), time());";

$parser = new PhpParser\Parser(new PhpParser\Lexer);
$prettyPrinter = new PhpParser\PrettyPrinter\Standard;

$statements = $parser->parse("<?php $code");

$result['function_name'] = $statements[0]->name->toString();
foreach ($statements[0]->args as $arg) {
    $result['arguments'][] = $prettyPrinter->prettyPrint(array($arg));
}

var_export($result);
```

#### Output:

```
array (
    'function_name' => '___echo',
    'arguments' =>
        array (
            0 => 'TODAY_IS',
            1 => 'date(\'j.n.Y\', time())',
            2 => 'time()',
        ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`token_get_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.token-get-all.php) function is what you need here:

```
token_get_all("<?php ___echo(TODAY_IS, date('j.n.Y', time()), time());")
```

This returns a list of tokens parsed from the given string. See the [tokens documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) for recognizing the items of the list.

In my opinion, tokenizer-based solution should be preferred over any regular expressions based on whatever is written in the PHP manual regarding syntax.